# How do you extract a value out of a golang map[string] string thats typed with interface{}

Tags: dictionary, go, types

I have something like this:

```
x1 := someFunctionWithAnInterfaceReturnValue()
```

and the underlying type is something like this:

```
x2 := map[string] string{"hello": "world"}
```

How would I access value in x1?

Essentially I want the equivalent of this for x1:

```
 var value string = x2["hello"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions):

```
x1 := someFunctionWithAnInterfaceReturnValue()
x2, ok := x1.(map[string]string)
if !ok {
   // handle unexpected type
}
var value string = x2["hello"]
```